# modify woocomerce pay button

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a seat booking plugin which does the necessary but has a huge issue, when users book the same seat, this plugin validation take place after users click the payment button no matter what payment method is selected.

E.G , user A started booking seat A1, then few secs after user B does to book the same seaT A1, since the system does not tell someone has the seat on process which im fine with still, the issue is that user A finishes his process completely, now user B got the check out page and until user click payment button and all the process is over then there is a notice on the product description, the sea A1 was taken already. now as you imagine that is a problem cause he already paid,

i was wondering may not be the right thing, but if i can make the payment button validate twice before finishing process or get the button to validate the seat is taken, then validate other pending fields but another click.

i got the pluging php file where it show the message,

```
   php?
   foreach($seatsSecF as $seat){
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'srw_seat_reservation_order';
        
        $checkOrderTable = $wpdb->prefix . 'srw_seat_reservation_order';
        if($schedule)
            $checkOrder = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * from $checkOrderTable where seat = '".$seat."' and proId = ".$proId." and schedule = '".$_SESSION["schedule".$proId]."'");
        else
            $checkOrder = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * from $checkOrderTable where seat = '".$seat."' and proId = ".$proId);
        
        if(!$checkOrder){
            if($newCheckSeats)
                $newCheckSeats .= "@".$seat;
            else
                $newCheckSeats .= $seat;
            $wpdb->insert( $table_name,
                array( 
                    'proId' => $proId, 
                    'orderId' => $order_key,
                    'seat' => $seat,
                    'schedule' => $_SESSION["schedule".$proId]
                ) 
            );
        }else{
            $newCheckSeats .= "<br><span style='red'>The seat ".$seat." was taken</span><br>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code you have shown lacks context, when can not tell _when_ this executes, resp. how exactly that gets triggered. Check what hooks/filters of the WooCommerce checkout process the plugin appends itself to, to perform this task. You might simply need to attach the same thing to a different hook that runs earlier in the process.

Comment: i thought the same at some point, but honestly i dont know what hook look like and what should exactly i shoud modifi, i tried adding a resturn false next to the notice, but this doesn't stop the process it only stop showing the message, at lease if i can get it to stop the process will be ok as well, here is a link to the entire file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/125wk0R6uFRfj5FqWO1uv9kBOMWRx1QfE/view?usp=sharing